# Javascript switch statement fails

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Probably a really silly problem, but: this prints 'yeeeeeees' in the console, but in the switch statement the Unknown step error is thrown.

What am I doing wrong?

```
        if (step === 'menuLoaded') console.log('yeeeeeeeees');
        switch (step) {
            case 'menuLoaded':
                this.window.activate_side_menu();
                this.handleDomainFtp();
                break;
            case 'ftpStep1':
                this.handleDomainFtp(1);
                break;
            case 'ftpStep2':
                this.handleDomainFtp(2);
                break;
            case 'startMysql':
                alert('starting mysql');
                this.handleDomainMysqlList();
                break;
            case 'mysqlList':
                this.handleDomainMysql();
                break;
            case 'mysqlPage':
                this.handleDomainMysql(true);
                break;
            case 'done':
                run();
                break;
            default:
                throw new Error('Unknown step: ' + step);
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Hmmm... it could be a 'typing' issue; what happens if you do `if (step == 'menuLoaded') console.log('yeeeeeeeees');`?  I'm not sure which comparison a switch would make, but I think it would be a `===` but perhaps not.

Comment: is `this.window` supposed to be just `window` ?

Comment: @Levi Morrison, if `===` produces the console log then it's not a typing issue.

Comment: It appears to be correct. Are you sure that step equals what you think it equals? What is its value when you debug? http://jsfiddle.net/YP2gy/1/

Comment: When I run your code, it works fine when I assign `'menuLoaded'` to `step`.

Comment: @OriginalSyn ah good point.  I am running on little sleep and didn't realized I made the guess on the wrong direction of generality.

Comment: That `break;` in the `default`case is is unreachable. Wouldn't cause and issue, but you might as well remove it.

Answer (score 1):

The error I'm getting is `TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'activate_side_menu'` - have you made sure to declare that function somewhere in the available scope?

Comment: Yeah, good point! :) Although I think if an error is thrown in one of the functions inside `case 'menuLoaded'`, the switch statement will automatically exit the current case and execute the default statement. So basically your switch statement may be working exactly as expected, but `this.window.activate_side_menu()` or `this.handleDomainFtp()` may be failing.

Comment: Having said that, I can't actually see anything in the ECMAscript docs to suggest that an error in a case clause should cause the current execution block to exit and fall through to the default clause.

Answer (score 0):

Since there apparently is no other way of closing my question I'll just answer it myself.

The problem was with the following code.
Later I have another switch statement with exactly the same Error() thrown.

Like I said, probably something silly....

But thanks for everyones time!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely needed to assign 'this' to 'var self' and use 'self' in place of this.

Answer (score 0):

try using the default statement without the "break;"

```
default:
            throw new Error('Unknown step: ' + step);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

<strike>I'm rather sure JavaScript's `switch()` won't accept strings - you have to use integer values. If you'd like to use names, use some enum like variables:</strike>

```
const step_menuLoaded = 0;
const step_menuFtp1 = 1;
const step_menuFtp2 = 2;
const step_startSql = 3;
...
```

Have you checked your code/source for non-printable characters inside the strings then?

Comment: Rather than being "rather sure" it might be better to just be "sure".  Javascript switch works fine with strings.

Comment: Haha, I was about to put up a jsfiddle myself.  I'm too tired I guess.  +1 @OriginalSyn